# Dynamically create multiple nested form in angular

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, forms

I am trying to create a form that can dynamically create multiple nested form. Here is a snippet of the html:

```
 <ng-form name="" ng-repeat="form in forms1">
            <button class="btn btn-success btn-md" ng-click="addNewSchedule(form)">
                    <i class="fa fa-plus-circle fa-fw"></i> Add Schedule
            </button><br>
            <div ng-repeat="cont in form.schedule">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <label>Base Date Key <span style="color: red;">*</span></label>
                            <select name="base_date_key" class="form-control" ng-model="cont.base_date_key" ng-options="base_key for base_key in base_date_key">
                                <option value="">Select Base Date Key</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <label>Forward Backward <span style="color: red;">*</span></label>
                            <select name="forward_backward" class="form-control" ng-model="cont.forward_backward" ng-options="forward for forward in forward_backward">
                                <option value="">Select Forward Backward Option</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <label>Schedule ID </label>
                                <input type="text" name="schedule_id" class="form-control" ng-model="cont.schedule_id">
                            </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <br>

            <hr>
              <ng-form>
                <button class="btn btn-success btn-md" ng-click="">
                    <i class="fa fa-plus-circle fa-fw"></i> Add Schedules
                </button><br>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <label>Schedule Amount <span style="color: red;">*</span></label>
                        <input type="text" name="schedule_amount" class="form-control" ng-model="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <label>Schedule Charge Code</label>
                        <select name="charge_code" class="form-control" ng-model="" ng-options="charge_two.key as charge_two.value for charge_two in schedule_charge_code track by charge_two.key">
                            <option value="">Select Schedule Charge Code</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <label>Frequency <span style="color: red;">*</span></label>
                        <input type="text" name="frequency" class="form-control" ng-model="">
                    </div>
                </div>

            <br>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <label>Schedule Date <span style="color: red;">*</span> </label>
                    <input type="text" 
                           class="form-control" 
                           datepicker-popup="yyyy-MM-dd" 
                           ng-model="bookloan.schedule_date" 
                           is-open="schedule_date.open" 
                           ng-click="schedule_date.open = true" 
                           datepicker-options="scheduleDateOptions" 
                           date-disabled="disabled(date, mode)" 
                           ng-required="true"
                           close-text="Close" />
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <label>Schedule Type <span style="color: red;">*</span></label>
                    <select name="schedule_type" class="form-control" ng-model="" ng-options="schedule for schedule in schedule_type">
                        <option value="">Select Schedule Type</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
           </ng-form>
        </ng-form>
```

What I have done so far, is when the user clicks the Add Schedule button it displays four input fields.Here is a snippet of the html code that is dynamically created when clicking the Add Schedule button:

```
            <div ng-repeat="cont in form.schedule">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <label>Base Date Key <span style="color: red;">*</span></label>
                            <select name="base_date_key" class="form-control" ng-model="cont.base_date_key" ng-options="base_key for base_key in base_date_key">
                                <option value="">Select Base Date Key</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <label>Forward Backward <span style="color: red;">*</span></label>
                            <select name="forward_backward" class="form-control" ng-model="cont.forward_backward" ng-options="forward for forward in forward_backward">
                                <option value="">Select Forward Backward Option</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <label>Schedule ID </label>
                                <input type="text" name="schedule_id" class="form-control" ng-model="cont.schedule_id">
                            </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Also, here is the JavaScript code that is able to create the dynamic input fields:

```
  var schedules; 
  $scope.forms1 = [{base_date_key: "",forward_backward: "",schedule_id:""}];
   $scope.addNewSchedule = function(form1){
                   console.log(form1.schedule);
                   if(typeof form1.schedule === 'undefined') {
                    form1.schedule = [];
                  }


                  form1.schedule.push({name:"",base_date_key: "",forward_backward: "",schedule_id: ""});

                  schedules = form1.schedule;

            };
```

Basically, how this should work is when you click the Add Schedule button which will display four form fields (which was mention above) and should also display Add Schedules Button. When clicking the Add Schedules button, it should dynamically add the Schedule Amount, Schedule Charge Code,Frequency,Schedule Date and the Schedule Type input fields.

Also the output of this in JavaScript should be like this:

```
[
  {
    schedule : [
                 {
                    base_date_key: "",
                    forward_backward:"",
                    schedule_id:"",
                    schedules : [
                                  {
                                     schedule_amount : "",
                                     schedule_charge_code: "",
                                     frequency: "",
                                     schedule_date: "",
                                     schedule_type: ""

                                  }
                                ]
                 }
               ]
    }
]
```

How can I accomplish this thanks in advance.

Comment: So what is the question ? What is not working ?

Comment: `ng-model` can not be `""`

Comment: @RayonDabre I want to know how I can go about dynamically add fields when clicking the Add Schedules button. I know that ng-model can not  be an empty string, I just not sure what to do in that part.

Comment: You do not need nested `ng-form` but `ng-repeat` inside `ng-repeat`..inner `ng-repeat` will repeat `schedules`

Comment: @newbieDev, **You can't insert nested forms in html !!!**

Comment: @ Abhilash P A- Pullelil, We can create nested **forms** in angular. Like this `<div ng-form="form1"><div ng-form="form2"></div></div>`.